# How to output field padding in file Scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file. Now, I want output field padding in file as `Exp1` & `Exp2`.
What should I do?
This is my input:

```
a
a a
a a a
a a a a
a a a a a
```

Exp1. Fill the remaining fields with the `-` character when each record in the file does not fit into the `n=4` field.

```
a _ _ _
a a _ _
a a a _
a a a a
a a a a a
```

Exp2. Same as above. Delete the fields after the `n=4` field when the number of fields in the record exceeds `n`.

```
a _ _ _
a a _ _
a a a _
a a a a
a a a a
```

My code:

```
val df = spark.read.text("data.txt")
val result = df.columns.foldLeft(df){(newdf, colname) => 
   newdf.withColumnRenamed(colname, colname.replace("a", "_"))
} 
result .show
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: @steven35, I have tried many times but have not found the solution for this problem.Please help me!

Comment: @JohnTrung You can share your code, even if it's not working correctly. People here will help you figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik, This is my code: val df = spark.read.text("data.txt")
val result = df.columns.foldLeft(df){(newdf, colname) => newdf.withColumnRenamed(colname, colname.replace("a", "_"))}
result .show

Comment: @JohnTrung I edited your question and added it.

Comment: @ Krzysztof Atłasik, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This resembles a homework-style problem, so I will help guide you based on your provided code and try to lead you on the right path here.

Your current code is only changing the name of the columns. In this case, the column name "value" is being changed to "v_lue". 
You want to change the actual records themselves.

First, you want to read this data into an RDD. It can be done with a dataframe, but being able to map on the row strings 
instead of Row objects might make this easier to understand conceptually. I'll get you started.

```scala
val data = sc.textFile("data.txt")
```

Data will be an RDD of strings, where each element is a line in the data file.

We're going to want to map this data to some new data, and transform each row.

```scala
data.map(row => {
   // transform each row here
})
```

Inside this map we make some change to row, which is a string. The code inside applies to every string in the RDD.

You will probably want to *split* the row to get an array of strings, so that you can count how many occurrences 
of 'a' there are. Depending on the size of the array, you will want to create a new string and output that from this map. 
If there are fewer 'a's than n, you will probably want to create a string with enough '_'s. If there are too many, 
you will probably want to return a string with the correct number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is your point like this?
val data = sc.textFile("data5.txt")
val outFile = data.map(x=>x.split("\t")).map(x => Array(x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4).replace(" ","_"))
outFile.foreach(println)

Comment: You're on the right track here, but let's look at a few things. First, it looks like the data here is separated by spaces, not tabs. You might want to change the split condition. Second, what are we replacing here? Are we replacing spaces with underscores?

Comment: Are we replacing spaces with underscores? -> That' s right. Please to edit code sample.

Comment: @JohnTrung as I mentioned above, try changing the code in your comment. Do we want to split by tabs? I don't think so. Do we want to replace spaces with underscores? I don't think so, either.

Comment: Do you have any better solution?
If you have solution, you can provide me with sample code.